# C++ Template - primary expression needed

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Error while compiling the following program using GCC/G++ compiler under cygwin environment -
/src/Template_1.cpp:66:2: error: expected primary-expression before ‘template’
  template TemplateCall::TemplateCall;
  ^

My source code is as below:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdarg>


using namespace std;

template<class T>
class TemplateCall
{
        private:
                T dataValue;
        public:
                TemplateCall(T somethingValue);
                void showTTParam();
};


template<class T>
TemplateCall<T>::TemplateCall(T somethingValue)
{
        cout << endl << " Calling TemplateCall - constructor " << endl;
        dataValue = somethingValue;
}

template<class T>
void TemplateCall<T>::showTTParam()
{
        cout << endl << " TemplateTemplateParam - showTTParam " << endl;
        cout << endl << " dataValue - showTTParam " << dataValue << endl;
}



int main()
{

        template TemplateCall<int>;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `template TemplateCall<int>;`?

Answer (score 5):

To create an instance of `TemplateCall<int>`, you need to use:

```
TemplateCall<int> obj;
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

To explicitly instantiate the class template, use

```
template class TemplateCall<int>;
```

but you need to use it outside of all functions.

Comment: Actually I need to test using "explicit instantiation".

Comment: Could you please explain me the reason why it is working if defined outside the function and not working while with in the function.

Comment: source :- 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template

Explicit instantiation
template class name < argument-list > ; (1) 
extern template class name < argument-list > ; (2) (since C++11)
1) Explicit instantiation definition
2) Explicit instantiation declaration
An explicit instantiation definition forces instantiation of the class, struct, or union they refer to. It may appear in the program anywhere after the template definition, and for a given argument-list, is only allowed to appear once in the entire program.

Regards,
Nandu Mishra

Comment: @NANDUMISHRA From the C++11 Standard (14.7.2/3): *If the name declared in the
explicit instantiation is an unqualified name, the explicit instantiation shall appear in the namespace where
its template is declared or, if that namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace
set.*